# Android Photo / Thumbnail Strategy using DiskLRUCache

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using [Jake Wharton's DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache) lib.

I'm curious about app performance, caching strategy, using caching both in a view and across a whole application. Most of the time, the image won't change.

Let's say for example I have a 320x320 photo on my server. I open the stream, save the image.

1. In my list views, I show bitmaps and in the detail, I show a larger image. Should I save a thumbnail bitmap too? Is that more efficient?
2. What is your experience with sharing the cache "object" across the entire app (let's say I have multiple views that might leverage the same data. What are the issues with this?
3. For the sake of performance and currency, what if the image changes on the server. What's the best strategy to know that it's changed? I don't have access to modified date. Only size and yet, I don't really want to query size every time either. Set a flag in the app on the server and then query the flag?

   1. In a traditional application (if there is such a thing), what's the best practice for clearing the cache from time to time? (indent weirded out.)

(I was inspired to write this after seeing all of the performance improvements by Facebook in iOS. I don't have billions to do caching but I would like to at least be smart about it! LOL)

Answer (score 3):

A lot of these answers depend on the type of app you're writing, how important image updates are (and how likely images will change, etc), and total images produced.  Aside from disk caching, you should be using memory caching as well, especially in ListViews and other areas where the same images will be scrolled through repeatedly. Look at [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) and read the [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) entry from Google.

320x320 is probably too big for a listview, you will likely want to create thumbnails (depending on device, and how you're implementing your listviews).

1) You should be using Disk caching fairly aggressively (how you define that is up to the app you're writing). Use the external storage directory, and if they have a few GB left over, it's not an issue if you take 100 mb for your app for instance.  It can all be cleared away if it's ever needed anyway.

2) There shouldn't be an issue. Disk IO (even to a flash medium) should never be handled on the main thread.  Use AsyncTasks to load the images. There can only be one main foreground activity at once anyway, and while an activity is sleeping, it shouldn't be trying to read from the disk anyway.

3) Again this depends on how you're implementing your app. You should be able to get additional information when retrieving the file (even Apache can tell your app the last modified date).
3.1) You can have a sqllite db that keeps track of how often certain images are used, and most recent read.  If the most recent read is a few days old, let that image expire.

Edit: There's a library from Jake Wharton now called Picasso that I would recommend using, which handles the Network/local IO as well as memory and disk caching. Check it ou here: http://square.github.io/picasso/ .  A lot of what you will need to do can be accomplished with one line: `Picasso.with(this).load(imageFileURL).into(imageView);`